# How handle cancel button of facebook dialog apprequest?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

As you know, you can display some facebook views to make some operations, like app requests, post etc. There is a delegate to manage the callbacks like : `dialogDidComplete:`, `dialogDidNotComplete:`. The view is like that :
[image]

But there is not differentiation between the cancel and share button. You will have the same callback in `dialogDidComplete:`. The only way to manage a cancelation is the little cross in the corner.
In my case I would like to do some operations if the user pressed share and not when he pressed Cancel.
The private social network Path manage this case and I'm wondering how ?

Do you guys have some ideas  ?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958912/facebook-api-how-to-cancel-graph-request) might be a similar question. See Wayne Liu's answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I am not wrong:

- if you press `Share` you get a `requestID` back as part of the returned URL
- if you press `Cancel` you are returned into `dialogDidComplete` but it does not return a `requestID` back as part of the returned URL.

Code:

```
- (void)dialogCompleteWithUrl:(NSURL *)url {
     if (![url query]) {
         NSLog(@"User canceled dialog or there was an error");
         return;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Probably in the sharing case, but there is nothing like that for an app request..

Comment: I haven't tried. But you can use the Hackbook sample and add a NSLog to the URL and see to it. This seems more like an implementation issue than a bug on our side. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I found the solution in the hackbook sample you mentioned. It's strange that the cancel callback is not made in `dialogDidNotCompleteWithUrl:`, `dialogDidNotComplete:` or `dialog:(FBDialog*)dialog didFailWithError:` .

Comment: I am also relying on the [url query], it is sad that Facebook did not use the dialogDidNotComplete: or dialog:didFailWithError: as the name implied...
for success, the url looks something like: fbconnect://success?request=298855633579176&to%5B0%5D=100003013638786
for failure, the url is just: fbconnect://success
sadly, it also contain success and not failure in the data